# Need to decode ascii for xml file, into literal characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii

I have an xml file that is being used on a third party system, and I have no control over the third party system that is using the xml file.

The third party system fails because there are ascii in the xml file.

For example, it fails when it sees

> `&#44;`

when it wants a single quote ’

Is there a way to throw php code around the variables and decode the ascii into plain text?

Comment: FYI, ascii *is* plain text (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii).  You're asking how to decode xml entities (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_entity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your strings through [`html_entity_decode()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).